# Azure AD B2C & Microsoft Identity Web - Sign In with multiple policies (.net Core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, microsoft-identity-web

I have an application using .NET Core 3.1 MVC Web App that uses Azure AD B2C to sign in users and I've just migrated it to use Microsoft Identity Web library.

We want to have two different policies for Sign In, one for regular users (**B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn**) and one for admin users (**B2C_1A_SignInAdmin**).
So, in the Appsettings, we have the following format:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://url.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "clientId",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn",
    "Domain": "url.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Domain_b2cLogin": "url", // Required by the Cookie Policy
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn",
    "SignInAdminPolicyId": "B2C_1A_SignInAdmin",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1A_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "",
    "ClientSecret": key,
    "B2cExtensionAppClientId": "key"
  },
```

In the Startup class, I just added the following:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

And I also overrode the "AzureController", so, for a regular user, I use the same method obtained from
here [Microsoft Identity Web - Account Controller](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs) "SignIn". However, for an admin user, I changed that method to use something similar to what is provided by the PasswordReset method, as the following:

```
        public IActionResult SignInAdmin()
    {
        string scheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
        properties.Items[Constants.Policy] = "B2C_1A_SignInAdmin";
        return Challenge(properties, scheme);
    }
```

So, as you can see, I'm using a different policy name for this method.

Everything seems to work fine, the user is redirected to the correct login page based on the policy and the token is issued by Azure and our application accepts the Token, in our method

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context => {}
```

However, soon after that, something goes wrong with the authentication and the method

```
options.Events.OnRemoteFailure
```

is called with the following exception
"{"Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. Actual Value : **B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn** and Expected Value : **B2C_1A_SignInAdmin** ..."

So, my question is, what do I have to do to be able to use two different policies to sign in? Or is there any configuration that I should do to be able to do that?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Thanks @Henrique and Could you please follow these two example and let us know if issue -error still persist - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs-popup/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI/Startup.cs#L30

Comment: @Jit_MSFT Do you have an example of this for .NET framework (4.7.2)?
I am specifically trying to call an API which I want to access with 2 different policies and applications.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the B2c Middleware validates the "tfp" claim. This should usually match the SignInPolicyId. You might have to override the TokenValidation to let both policies (tfp = trustedFrameworkPolicy) be valid